# What does decay_steps mean in Tensorflow tf.train.exponential_decay?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, gradient-descent, tensorflow, adam

I am trying to implement an [exponential learning rate decay](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/exponential_decay) with the Adam optimizer for a LSTM. I do not want the 'staircase = true' version. The decay_steps for me feels like the number of steps that the learning rate keeps constant. But I am not sure about this and Tensorflow has not stated it in their documentation.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just so you know, Adam already handles learning rate optimization.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in [the code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/python/training/learning_rate_decay.py) of the function the relation of `decay_steps` with `decayed_learning_rate` is the following:

```
decayed_learning_rate = learning_rate *
                      decay_rate ^ (global_step / decay_steps)
```

Hence, you should set the `decay_steps` proportional to the `global_step` of the algorithm.